# Load object from Asset Bundle

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have Download and Main cs files. The first one contains method LoadAsset

```
public IEnumerator  LoadAsset(string link, string loadObject)
{
WWW download;
string ErrorMsg=" ";
download = new WWW(link);
yield return download;

if (download.error != null)
{
   ErrorMsg=download.error;
}
else
{
   ErrorMsg="Downloading ....";
   AssetBundle asset = download.assetBundle;
       GameObject loadedObject;
loadedObject = Instantiate(asset.Load(loadObject,typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;

   asset.Unload(false);
   ErrorMsg="Done";
}   
   Debug.Log(ErrorMsg);
}
```

I want to call this method from Main.cs file and return loadedObject in it. Tried to use StartCoroutine

```
Download download; 
download=new Download(); 
StartCoroutine("download.LoadAsset()");
```

but without success. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without the quotes

```
StartCoroutine( download.LoadAsset() )
```

You add the quotes when you want to cancel it, but it won't work on a method outside your class.

It would be event better to add a method to your Main.cs that starts the coroutine for you, something like this

```
public void StartLoadAssetCo()
{
  StartCoroutine(LoadAsset());
}
```

and then just call **StartLoadAssetCo** from outside the class

```
download.StartLoadAssetCo();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. One more question. How can I return GameObject with StartCoroutine method>

Comment: You can't return objects from a Coroutine, but you can either register a callback in your Download class that gets called with the GameObject as a param when the method finishes or use an lambda function that is passed as param to the LoadAsset

Comment: can you give me specific example, it'll help me.

Comment: LoadAsset(string link, string loadObject, Action<GameObject> callback){ .... else{ ... callback(loadedObject) } }, this way callback gets called when the gameobject is available

Comment: What about call LoadAsset? Download download;
   download=new Download();
   System.Action<GameObject> go=null;
 StartCoroutine(download.LoadAsset("http://localhost/3dobjects?key=11","car13",go));

Comment: you need to assign something to go, like this System.Action<GameObject> go = (GameObject go){ //do something with go } }